# IE centering and possible image problem

Tags: html, css

Here is my test link to a my portfolio I'm trying to finish up - http://dev.nerdysyntax.com.

First problem is my images seem to distort or blob transition into focus when first open. Most advanced sites I've seen where images usually appear starting from the top of the image to the bottom. Not sure if that is standard, but my image focusing doesn't seem normal. Is something wrong with my script for images?

Second and biggest problem is centering in IE. My site is centered fine in all other browsers except for IE9 and older. Even my footer seems to be out of whack in IE. Can anyone help with either of these problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the `!` in the Doctype. You are probably pushing IE into Quirks mode. [Validating](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.nerdysyntax.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) would have picked this up.

Comment: Yep that seemed to do it. Now I got some padding and margin problems that are new, but at least all the browsers seem consistent. Thanks.